# The Logic behind Reserving a Window for the Picture Environment

Tags: graphics, diagrams

What is the point of reserving a space or window when creating a figure using the picture environment?
I mean if I have the following setup:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.5mm}
\frame{
    \begin{picture}(80,60)(0,0)
        \put(0,0){\circle*{3}}
        \put(-10,-10){\circle*{3}}
        \put(180,-10){\circle*{3}}
    \end{picture}}
```

I will get this result

---

[image]

-----------------------------------------------------
This simply means that I can draw elements outside the boundaries of that space, so why does it exist in the first place? In other words, what does it represent, or why it's in the background?

Comment: it represents the place LaTeX will see "occupied" and not  fill with other things like text.

Comment: Ok, that seems fair enough. Thanks

Comment: This is similar to the bounding box or viewport.

Comment: note your `\frame{` should have a `%` as you ar framing a space to the left of the picture but not the right

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the hint.